# Plotting 3d in python with DiracDelta function

Tags: sympy, plot3d

I am trying to plot a two variable function
A simple function `x*DiracDelta(y)+y*DiracDelta(x)`
code will work with simple function without DiracDelta But when I enter the delta function, it gives an error?
Can you help me find the problem with this code?

```py
from sympy import symbols, DiracDelta
from sympy.plotting import plot_parametric
from sympy import symbols, DiracDelta
from sympy.plotting import plot3d

x, y = symbols('x y')
f = x*DiracDelta(y)+y*DiracDelta(x)

plot3d(f, (x, -1, 1), (y, -1, 1))
```

Thanks!

try to plot a 3d function It works when I have function without Delta function but it give me error when put delta function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### About DiracDelta in general

The Dirac distribution is ***not*** a function in the mathematical sense.

The [sympy documentation for sympy.DiracDelta](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/functions/special.html#dirac-delta-and-related-discontinuous-functions) states it explicitly:

> DiracDelta is not an ordinary function. It can be rigorously defined either as a distribution or as a measure.
>
> DiracDelta only makes sense in definite integrals, [...] care must be taken to not treat it as a real function. [...] if DiracDelta is treated too much like a function, it is easy to get wrong or nonsensical results.

So, you can't plot it like a function, because it isn't a function.

In simple words, the Dirac distribution behaves like a function that is 0 [*almost everywhere*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_everywhere), but has an integral of 1 in any interval that includes 0.

Intuitively, if it could be plotted like a function, the Dirac distribution would have a plot that looks kinda like this:

[image: Plot of Dirac Delta]

Except the width of the peak should be 0, and the area under the peak should be exactly 1. This of course would be self-contradictory for a function, so no plot will be truly satisfactory. Again, the Dirac distribution is not a function.

### About your `f = x*DiracDelta(y)+y*DiracDelta(x)`

Again, f is not a function in the mathematical sense. It will behave like a function that is 0 almost everywhere, but with an integral equal to `(x2**2 - x1**2)/2` on regions that intersect segment [x1, x2] on the x-axis, and an integral equal to `(y2**2 - y1**2)/2` on regions that intersect segment [y1, y2] on the y-axis.

Instead of plotting `f`, which won't work since `f` is not a function, I suggest approximating `DiracDelta` by a "peak" function like the one I drew above, and plot an approximation of `f` using this approximation of `DiracDelta`. For instance:

```py
# approximating DiracDelta by a piecewise-affine peak function
from sympy import Piecewise

def dn(x, n):
    return Piecewise(
        (0,               x <= -1/n),
        (n + n**2 * x,    x <= 0),
        (n - n**2 * x,    x <= 1/n),
        (0,               True)
    )


from sympy import symbols, DiracDelta
x, y = symbols('x y')
f = x * DiracDelta(y) + y * DiracDelta(x)

n = 20
fn = x * dn(y, n) + y * dn(x, n)

# now plot fn instead of f
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation
If I want to draw the integral of this function
I add the following line to the code

Comment: Thanks for the explanation
If I want to draw the integral of this function
I add the following line to the code
from sympy import symbols, DiracDelta
from sympy.plotting import plot3d

x, y = symbols('x y')
f = x*DiracDelta(y)+y*DiracDelta(x)
f1=x+y

z=sp.integrate(f, x,y)
z1=sp.integrate(f1, x,y)


plot3d(z, (x, -1, 1), (y, -1, 1))
plot3d(z1, (x, -1, 1), (y, -1, 1))

but But the integrated function is still not plot

Comment: @AliRezaMohammadi Alternatively, you can define a "peak" function `dn(x, n)`, affine by parts, with `dn(x, n) = 0` when `x <= -1/n` or `x >= 1/n`, `dn(0, n) = n`, `dn(x, n) = n - n**2 * x` when `0 <= x <= 1/n`, and `dn(x, n) = n + n**2 * x` when `-1/n <= x <= 0`. Then `dn` is an approximation of `DiracDelta`: it's 0 when `x` is not too close to 0, and its integral around 0 is equal to 1. And then, instead of plotting `f = x * DiracDelta(y) + y * DiracDelta(x)`, you choose a large value of `n` and you plot `fn = x * dn(y, n) + y * dn(x, n)`.

Comment: @AliRezaMohammadi Sorry, I meant piecewise-affine, not affine by part.